# how to style slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider

how to style **jQuery slider** like *bar width, color, size*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the

[Theming](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider)

section

The jQuery UI Slider plugin uses the jQuery UI CSS Framework to style its look and feel, including colors and background textures. We recommend using the ThemeRoller tool to create and download custom themes that are easy to build and maintain.

If a deeper level of customization is needed, there are widget-specific classes referenced within the ui.slider.css stylesheet that can be modified. These classes are highlighed in bold below.
Sample markup with jQuery UI CSS Framework classes

```
<div class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
   <a style="left: 0%;" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Note: This is a sample of markup generated by the slider plugin, not markup you should use to create a slider. The only markup needed for that is `<div><div>`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a styling tool right on the jquery website at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/